# transform:translate(10%)とするとずれる。

Tags: html, css

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

CSSでtranslate(10%)とすると、期待する移動距離になりません。（画像右端の青い隙間）
translate(50px)とpxで指定するとうまくいきます。
%の指定の際に留意する点などがあるのでしょうか？

[HTML]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>TEST</title>

<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="box box-left">

    </div>
    <div class="box box-right">

    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[CSS]

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.container{
    width: 500px;
    background: blue;
    position:relative;
}


.box-left{
    width: 10%;
    height: 500px;
    background: tomato;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}


.box-right{
    width: 90%;
    height: 500px;
    background: green;
    transform: translate(10%);/*50pxとするとうまくいく*/
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`transform: translate(10%);`の10％は`width:90%;`すなわち`width:450px;`に対するもので、この場合`45px`です。
10％左にあけたい場合は`margin-left:10%;`がよいかと思います。